# In a multithreaded application, how to prevent a thread to modify data which is being already modified by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Suppose, I have an application deployed on 3 nodes and from each node, one thread is trying to fetch and update the same data record at the same time. Data can only be fetched and updated from the central database. A method that is making the database connection, is thread safe. In this scenario, Is it possible that data can be modified and lead to inconsistency? If yes, how can we solve this problem?

Comment: The standard solution is to use database transactions and perform the fetch / update in a single transaction.  If you do it correctly, two clients doing a fetch / update will be serialized.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing several completely different things together:

- In general, to protect "data" between "threads", one would use a "lock".  One way of protecting data in Java is with [synchronized](https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized).
- In general, a "thread" running on one "node" cannot - and will not - interfere with in-memory data objects being manipulated by some thread on a different "node".
- "Database access" brings completely different issues to the table.  In particular, read up about [isolation levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-ver15)
- Finally, *IF* you're doing "database updates" and *IF* "concurrency" is an issue ... then you probably want to perform your update(s) within a DB [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

  A "transaction" is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID):

  - Atomic
  - Consistency
  - Isolation
  - Durability

Comment: [Here’s a better link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) than baeldung.com.